# $1 +\sqrt{-n}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have established a norm $N(x) = a^2 + nb^2$ with the properties $N(x)N(y) = N(xy)$ and $N(x) = 1$ implies $x = \pm 1$. I've figured out how to show $2$ and $\sqrt{-n}$ as irreducible using this norm, but I can't get $1 + \sqrt{-n}$ to work for me. This is what I have:

> If $1 + \sqrt{-n}$ were reducible in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-n}]$, there would be integers a and b so that 
>   $(a^2 + nb^2)|(n + 1)$ and $a^2 + nb^2 \ne n + 1$. So for some some integer $j$ so that $|j| \gt 1$, $j(a^2 + nb^2) = n + 1$. If $a = 0$, then $jnb^2 = n + 1$, so $jb^2 = 1 + \frac 1n$, which is not an integer; if $b = 0$, then $ja^2 = n + 1$

I have established the initial ideas in the argument for $\sqrt{-n}$, hence their brief treatment here. I really just need to find why a and b have to both be 1, and this is where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose that $1+\sqrt{-n}=(a+b\sqrt{-n})(c+d\sqrt{-n})$, with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Z$. Taking norm we get $j(a^2+nb^2)=n+1$, where $j=c^2+nd^2$. Then $j\geq1$ (assuming that $n\geq1$, which seems to be your case).

If $a,b\ne0$ then we have $0=(ja^2-1)+n(jb^2-1)$; since $ja^2-1\geq0$ and $jb^2-1\geq0$, it follows that in fact $ja^2=1$ and $jb^2=1$, so necessarily $j=1$, which in turn implies that $c+d\sqrt{-n}$ is a unit in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-n}]$.

As you pointed out, $a=0$ is impossible (because this implies that $n$ divides $1$). Finally, if $b=0$, the original equation becomes $1+\sqrt{-n}=ac+ad\sqrt{-n}$, which implies $ac=1$, and so $a+b\sqrt{-n}$ is a unit in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-n}]$. Since $N(1+\sqrt{-n})\ne\pm1$ then $1+\sqrt{-n}$ is not a unit, so it is irreducible.

Comment: I forgot to mention that n is a squarefree integer greater than 3. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For any element $a+b\sqrt{-n} \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$, define the norm function as $N(a+b\sqrt{-n}) = a^2 + nb^2$.

We need to show that $1+\sqrt{-n}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$, that is if we let $1+\sqrt{-n} = \alpha \cdot \beta$ for some $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$, then either $\alpha$ is a unit or $\beta$ is a unit. In other words, either $N(\alpha) = \pm1$ or $N(\beta) = \pm1$.

Let $\alpha = a+b\sqrt{-n}$ and $\beta = c+d\sqrt{-n}$ for $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then

$$1+\sqrt{-n} = (a+b\sqrt{-n})(c+d\sqrt{-n})$$
$$\implies N(1+\sqrt{-n}) = N((a+b\sqrt{-n})(c+d\sqrt{-n}))$$
$$\implies N(1+\sqrt{-n}) = N(a+b\sqrt{-n}) \cdot N(c+d\sqrt{-n})$$
$$\implies 1+n = (a^2+nb^2)(c^2 + nd^2)$$
$$\implies 1+n = a^2c^2 + n(a^2d^2 + b^2c^2) + n^2b^2d^2$$
For the equality to hold, we will necessarily have $b^2d^2 = 0 \implies bd = 0 \implies b = 0 \; or \; d = 0$ (Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain).

Further, $a^2c^2 = 1 \implies a=1 \; and \; c = 1$ (as both $a,c \in \mathbb{Z}$).

Finally, $a^2d^2 + b^2c^2 = 1$ ...(1)

*Case 1:* If $b = 0$, we have from (1), $a^2d^2 = 1 \implies d = \pm 1$ (as $a=1$).

Thus, $a = 1, b = 0, c = 1, d = \pm 1 \implies N(\alpha) = 1 \implies \alpha$ is a unit.

*Case 2:* If $d = 0$, then we have from (1), $b^2c^2 = 1 \implies b = \pm 1$.

Thus, $a = 1, b = \pm 1, c = 1, d = 0 \implies N(\beta) = 1 \implies \beta$ is a unit.
$$$$

Note that if both $b$ and $d$ are $0$, then both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are units.

Thus in all cases, we have that $1+\sqrt{-n}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$. $\; \blacksquare$